# Draggable Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DRAG & DROP</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
//try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"e249f4e174edf7af03a74bc76c145d98",petok:"4a10f38bb2d4b46c1cff3e9e6e64e00d2795f082-1436193605-1800",zone:"oc-static.com",rocket:"0",apps:{}}];CloudFlare.push({"apps":{"ape":"4a1bcba3f7297e6bc2869c4a33323412"}});!function(a,b){a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],a.async=!0,a.src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=7e13c32551/cloudflare.min.js",b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}()}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
<style>
      .dropper {
    display: inline-block;
          margin: 50px 10px 10px 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
          background-color: #555;
          border: 1px solid #111;
          
          -moz-border-radius: 10px;
          border-radius: 10px;
          
          -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
          -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
          -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
          transition: all 200ms linear;
      }

      .drop_hover {
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
          box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
      }

      .draggable {
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
          padding-top: 20px;
          width: 60px;
          height: 30px;
          color: #3D110F;
          background-color: #822520;
          border: 4px solid #3D110F;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 1em;
          cursor: move;
          
          -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
          -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
          -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
          transition: all 200ms linear;
          
          -moz-user-select: none;
          -khtml-user-select: none;
          -webkit-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
 
  <div class="dropper">
       
        <div class="draggable">Block1</div>
        <div class="draggable">Block2</div>
        <div class="draggable">Block3</div>

  
    </div>
 
 <div class="dropper">

      
    </div>

 <script>
 var x=document.querySelectorAll('.dropper');
  x[0].style.height="600px";
  x[0].style.width="200px";
  
  
  x[1].style.height="600px";
  x[1].style.width="999px";
  
   </script>
​


    <script>
    (function() {
    
    var dndHandler = {
        
        draggedElement: null, // Propriété pointant vers l'élément en cours de déplacement
        
        applyDragEvents: function(element) {
            
            element.draggable = true;

            var dndHandler = this; // Cette variable est nécessaire pour que l'événement « dragstart » ci-dessous accède facilement au namespace « dndHandler »
            
            element.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
                dndHandler.draggedElement = e.target; // On sauvegarde l'élément en cours de déplacement
                e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', ''); // Nécessaire pour Firefox
    
   }, false);
            
        },
 
        applyDropEvents: function(dropper) {
            
            dropper.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // On autorise le drop d'éléments
                this.className = 'dropper drop_hover'; // Et on applique le style adéquat à notre zone de drop quand un élément la survole
            }, false);
            
            dropper.addEventListener('dragleave', function() {
                this.className = 'dropper'; // On revient au style de base lorsque l'élément quitte la zone de drop
            });
            
            var dndHandler = this; // Cette variable est nécessaire pour que l'événement « drop » ci-dessous accède facilement au namespace « dndHandler »

            dropper.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {

                var target = e.target,
                    draggedElement = dndHandler.draggedElement, // Récupération de l'élément concerné
                    clonedElement = draggedElement.cloneNode(true); // On créé immédiatement le clone de cet élément
                
                while (target.className.indexOf('dropper') == -1) { // Cette boucle permet de remonter jusqu'à la zone de drop parente
                    target = target.parentNode;
                }

                target.className = 'dropper'; // Application du style par défaut
                
                clonedElement = target.appendChild(clonedElement); // Ajout de l'élément cloné à la zone de drop actuelle
                dndHandler.applyDragEvents(clonedElement); // Nouvelle application des événements qui ont été perdus lors du cloneNode()
                
                draggedElement.parentNode.removeChild(clonedElement);    // Suppression de l'élément d'origine
                
            });
            
        }
 
    };
    
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable'),
        elementsLen = elements.length;
    
    for (var i = 0 ; i < elementsLen ; i++) {
        dndHandler.applyDragEvents(elements[i]); // Application des paramètres nécessaires aux éléments déplaçables
    }
    
    var droppers = document.querySelectorAll('.dropper'),

        droppersLen = droppers.length;
    
    //for (var i = 0 ; i < droppersLen ; i++) {
        dndHandler.applyDropEvents(droppers[1]); // Application des événements nécessaires aux zones de drop
    //}

 })();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I started programming using html/css/jquery/jscript. I had to make two blocks. We can drag elements from the left block to put them on the right one. And we can't do the opposit. In addition to that the elements on the left are not deleted when dragged. Here is my code:

```
(function() {

            var dndHandler = {

                draggedElement: null, // Propriété pointant vers l'élément en cours de déplacement

                applyDragEvents: function(element) {

                    element.draggable = true;

                    var dndHandler = this; // Cette variable est nécessaire pour que l'événement « dragstart » ci-dessous accède facilement au namespace « dndHandler »

                    element.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
                        dndHandler.draggedElement = e.target; // On sauvegarde l'élément en cours de déplacement
                        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', ''); // Nécessaire pour Firefox
                    }, false);

                },

                applyDropEvents: function(dropper) {

                    dropper.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault(); // On autorise le drop d'éléments
                        this.className = 'dropper drop_hover'; // Et on applique le style adéquat à notre zone de drop quand un élément la survole
                    }, false);

                    dropper.addEventListener('dragleave', function() {
                        this.className = 'dropper'; // On revient au style de base lorsque l'élément quitte la zone de drop
                    });

                    var dndHandler = this; // Cette variable est nécessaire pour que l'événement « drop » ci-dessous accède facilement au namespace « dndHandler »

                    dropper.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {

                        var target = e.target,
                        draggedElement = dndHandler.draggedElement, // Récupération de l'élément concerné
                        clonedElement = draggedElement.cloneNode(true); // On créé immédiatement le clone de cet élément

                        while (target.className.indexOf('dropper') == -1) { // Cette boucle permet de remonter jusqu'à la zone de drop parente
                            target = target.parentNode;
                        }

                        target.className = 'dropper'; // Application du style par défaut

                        clonedElement = target.appendChild(clonedElement); // Ajout de l'élément cloné à la zone de drop actuelle
                        dndHandler.applyDragEvents(clonedElement); // Nouvelle application des événements qui ont été perdus lors du cloneNode()

                        draggedElement.parentNode.removeChild(clonedElement); // Suppression de l'élément d'origine

                    });

                }

            };

            var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable'),
            elementsLen = elements.length;

            for (var i = 0 ; i < elementsLen ; i++) {
                dndHandler.applyDragEvents(elements[i]); // Application des paramètres nécessaires aux éléments déplaçables
            }

            var droppers = document.querySelectorAll('.dropper'),

            droppersLen = droppers.length;

            //for (var i = 0 ; i < droppersLen ; i++) {
                dndHandler.applyDropEvents(droppers[1]); // Application des événements nécessaires aux zones de drop
            //}

        })();}
```

My problem is when the elements are on the right block, they're positioned inline-block. I want to be able to drag them where ever I want in the block.
I found a way that make my element draggable where ever I want. But it's applied on the left block too:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dg1" ).draggable();            
});
```

What I want is: When the elements are on the left block, they stay inline-block. And when I drag them to the right block, I want to be able to put them where ever I want in that block.

Hope my question was clear enough and thank you for your answers!

---

```js
$(function(){
    $('.draggable').draggable({
     revert: 'invalid',
     opacity: 0.35,
     helper: function(){
      return $(this).clone().appendTo('#drop_in').css({'zIndex':5});
     },
     cursor: 'move',
     //containment: '#drop_in'
     
     
    });
    
    $('#drop_in').droppable({
     activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
     accept: '.draggable',
     drop: function(event, ui){
      if (!ui.draggable.hasClass("dropped"))
       $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone().addClass("dropped").draggable({containment: '#drop_in'}));
     }
    });
    
    
   });
```

```css
.draggable{
    
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1p solid #999;
    background: white;
    
    width: 100px; height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
   }
  
  
   .dropper{
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1p solid #999;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#CCCCCC,#EEEEEE);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#CCCCCC, #EEEEEE);
    width: 600px; height: 200px;
    padding-top: 20px;
   }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Droppable </title>
  
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="dropper" id="drag_from">
   <div class="draggable">Drag me!</div>
   <div class="draggable">Drag me too!</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="dropper" id="drop_in">
  </div>
 </body>
 
 
</html>
```

My problem is that when I drag the element and put it in the dropper, it isn't dropped where my mouse dropped it. But after the drop I can manipulate it and change its position. How can I change that in my code?

Comment: Would you mind adding the HTML? And maybe even creating a [runnable code snippet](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets)?

Comment: I created a runnable code snippet.

Comment: "I started programming using html/css/jquery/jscript.", so this is some kind of school assignment?

Comment: I'm on an internship where I'm supposed to create an application website to make something like a Grafcet. Like in the snippet, a block contains tools and a block where we can put tools and link them to each other. And a button that is going to generate a script depending on the order of the tools.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are assigned to this as an intern, giving a complete answer (including finished code) will not serve the purpose of the assignment: to learn how to make this yourself. It also surprises me to see you asking this question here instead of being helped by your supervisor; (s)he has the task to help you learn...

#### Now, to give an answer to the actual question:

The thing that you are (currently) dragging isn't actually the element itself, it some browser visualisation of a drag. jQuery-UI's $.draggable() isn't going to help you either cause it doesn't allow you to start a drag/drop on any other element (so not on cloned elements or the like).

You might want to write your own drag/drop code using jQuery, in that case the following functions might come in handy:

- [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) (to determine the absolute position to the page)
- [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) (to determine the relative position of the element)
- [event.pageX, event.pageY](http://api.jquery.com/event.pagex/) (to get the mouse position)
- using `$(':hover');` you can get all elements currently under your mouse

Personally I would listen to the `mousedown` on the blocks, clone the current block, add it to the `body` and set it to the correct position.
Listen to `mousemove` and `mouseup` on the body/document. Move the cloned element accordingly to the mouse position on `mousemove` and either remove the cloned element on `mouseup` or add it to the right droparea.

---

We are corresponding about this for a couple of days now. We can keep this up like forever, but that would not serve any purpose either. So here's some sample code including comments. Please study it carefully and try to understand the "way of thinking". If there is any part you don't understand, don't hesitate to ask ;)

```js
!function(e){var n=!1,o=!0;e.elementFromPoint=function(t,l){if(!document.elementFromPoint)return null;if(!n){var m;(m=e(document).scrollTop())>0?o=null==document.elementFromPoint(0,m+e(window).height()-1):(m=e(document).scrollLeft())>0&&(o=null==document.elementFromPoint(m+e(window).width()-1,0)),n=m>0}return o||(t+=e(document).scrollLeft(),l+=e(document).scrollTop()),e(document.elementFromPoint(t,l))}}(jQuery);

//create a variable accessible between the events:
var dragging = { $element: null, offset: { left: 0, top: 0 } };

//listen for mousedown on .draggable inside .dropper#drag_from:
$('.dropper#drag_from').on('mousedown', '.draggable', function(event){
    //prevent normal behaviour (selecting text etc.):
    event.preventDefault();
    //clone this .draggable element:
    dragging.$element  = $(this).clone();
    //determine the position of the mouse relative to this .draggable element:
    dragging.offset.left = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    dragging.offset.top = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    //set the element to `absolute` so it does not intervene with other elements, correct the position relative to the page, correct the margin and don't capture mouse events (necessary for $(':hover')):
    dragging.$element.css({ position: 'absolute', left: event.pageX - dragging.offset.left, top: event.pageY - dragging.offset.top, margin: '0', 'pointer-events': 'none' });
    //finally, append our cloned element to the body element of the page:
    $('body').append(dragging.$element);
});

//listen to both mousemove and mouseup anywhere on the page:
$('body').on('mousemove', function(event) {
    //only when dragging:
    if(dragging.$element) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //move element to the correct position:
        dragging.$element.css({ left: event.pageX - dragging.offset.left, top: event.pageY - dragging.offset.top });
    }
}).on('mouseup', function(event) {
    //only when dragging:
    if(dragging.$element) {
        //when hovering over the dropper:
        if($.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY).prop('id') == 'drop_in') {
            //set location relative to the dropper:
            dragging.$element.css({ left: event.pageX - $('.dropper#drop_in').offset().left - dragging.offset.left, top: event.pageY - $('.dropper#drop_in').offset().top - dragging.offset.top })
            //move element from the body to the dropper:
            $('.dropper#drop_in').append(dragging.$element);
        } else {
            //remove cloned element from document:
            dragging.$element.remove();
        }
        //no longer dragging:
        dragging.$element = null;
    }
});
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.draggable{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1p solid #999;
    background: white;
    
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropper{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1p solid #999;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#CCCCCC,#EEEEEE);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#CCCCCC, #EEEEEE);
    
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 50px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.dropper#drag_from{
    width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Droppable </title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dropper" id="drag_from">
            <div class="draggable">Drag me!</div>
            <div class="draggable">Drag me too!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropper" id="drop_in"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but it doesn't work. I'll try to clarify my question. What I want is something like this: http://live.yworks.com/demobrowser/index.html#Business-Process-Models

I think i have and idea but I don't know how to do it.

If(the draggable position is higher, for exemple than 50px top and 200px left) { 
$(function() {
    $( "#dg1" ).draggable();            
});
}

It means that when i drag the elements to the right block, it becomes draggable() which will allow me to drop them where ever i want.

Comment: Or is there a way to give the cloned elements a class so I can apply the function I want on them?

Comment: Well, your current code doesn't use any library, $.draggable() seems to be jQuery UI though. I would recommend to either finish writing your code in plain JS or create something using that library to keep your code clean and readable/understandable.

Comment: I rewrote my answer since it occured to me you aren't really dragging anything, only the browser does.

Comment: Thank you I rewrote the code using only jQuery. I'll put it as a snippet. I still have one small problem. I'll explain it in the answer

Comment: You are still using jQuery-UI. In my opinion it would be better to write your code without jQuery-UI (in this case). I changed my answer to include a code sample. Please use this to learn, not just to copy-paste!

Comment: I don't know if this is supposed to work because it doesn't. I see what you want to do. But I'm not familiar yet with all those functions to use them the way you did.

Comment: I only tested it in Firefox, apparently `$(':hover')` does not give the same results in Chrome. The code has been adjusted to work with [document.elementFromPoint](http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution), and now works in Chrome also.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test the Draggabilly plugin? It's awesome and full of functionalities. I think that your problem can solve with some of its methods

http://draggabilly.desandro.com/

You can drag on a grid, parent elements, limits of dragging, and event manipulation.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't see much differences between draggabilly plugin and normal jQuery